# Critical or acceptable value of forecasting error

Tags: forecasting, error

I'm new in R and data mining. I have question about critical or acceptable value of forecasting error. I created 30 days forecast of the parameters for working powered roof support in mine (very specific process). I use Census-I method and neural networks. For measure of forcast error I used SPE.

**My question**: Is there any criteria or acceptable value of forecasting error. I accepted 6%.